# Meteor.js collection & user permission structure

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-collections

We are starting development of a meteor app that allows users to create a profile, submit a set of search criteria and receive products (held in the app's db) curated by an administrator. I am wondering what the most elegant way of setting up the collections for this would be.

So far, our thinking is to:

> 1. Automatically generate user id's (accounts-ui package) and roles (alanning:meteor-roles package) as soon as the search process is
>      started
> 2. Add all user information, including the user id and role generated in step 1, to a "clients" collection
> 3. Add all search criteria selected by the user, as well as the user-id, to a separate "searches" collection.
> 4. Use search criteria to filter objects in a "products" collection, and deliver results to an admin who then manually curates from
>      filtered results.

Given the information I've provided, does this sound like the most elegant structure?

Comment: A bit opinion-based and also vague. Do you get an email from the user? Will they be back? Or is everyone anonymous and this is really session-based?

Comment: @MichelFloyd - Apologies for the vagueness. To answer your questions: 1 - we do get an email from the user; 2 - yes, they will be back.Once they've submitted their criteria (in this case a list of requirements for an event they're planning), the request is sent to the administrator, who can then see a shortlist of venues that are filtered through some of the criteria that the user gave. The administrator then manually chooses venues from this shortlist. Then, an e-mail is sent to the user to log in and see the suggested venues. I hope that is a little more clear!

Comment: ok. Your structure will work. *Elegant* is in the eye of the beholder ;) The role of the `clients` collection is a bit unclear, are clients 1:m with users or 1:1? If the latter then that collection may not be necessary as all the data could just be added to the user document.

Comment: @MichelFloyd - great, thank you.